# Visa application issues for non-EU spouse to join EU husband

Tags: spouses, afghan-citizens, freedom-of-movement

I am a British citizen living in Spain. My wife is a non-EU citizen from Afghanistan. Spain doesn't have an embassy in Afghanistan, so all visa applications are processed through the French Embassy.  I applied for my wife's visa, but the receptionist didn't know about Directive 2004/38/EC.  She charged us the usual Schengen visa fees, although I stipulated in a cover letter that we were applying under the directive.

Will the reviewing official understand and apply the directive? If not, I think there is a chance of refusal as the French are very strict about issuing visas.

What can we do to make sure that my wife's application won't be rejected?

Comment: ??? The Foreign Office from Spain lists one ambassy at Kabul: http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/KABUL/es/Embajada/Paginas/HorariosLocalizacionContacto.aspx

Comment: You should seek a refund of the visa application fee. But you're basically asking us to guess whether the officer who will review your application is good at his or her job. That's beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: thanks sjuan let see what the result then i will share it thanks again

Comment: got refused french embassy didnt follow eu directive